# AngularJS - exposing controller api to directive

Tags: angularjs

How do I make controller functions visible to a directive? Do I attach the methods to the scope, and inject the scope into the directive? Is it a good idea in the first place? I want to manipulate model data from within the UI.

Answer (score 2):

It really dependes on what you want to do.
Since you want to access the controller's scope from the directive, I suggest you [declare your directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile#description_comprehensive-directive-api_directive-definition-object) with it's scope shared with the parent controller by setting it's `scope` prop to `false`:

```
app.directive('directiveName', function() {
    scope: false, 
    link: function(scope) {
       // access foo from the controler's scope 
       scope.foo;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a nice example with how directives can be hooked up to a controller

http://jsfiddle.net/simpulton/GeAAB/

**DIRECTIVE**

```
myModule.directive('myComponent', function(mySharedService) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: function($scope, $attrs, mySharedService) {
        $scope.$on('handleBroadcast', function() {
            $scope.message = 'Directive: ' + mySharedService.message;
        });
    },
    replace: true,
    template: '<input>'
};
```

});

**HOOKUP IN CONTROLLER**

```
sharedService.broadcastItem = function() {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('handleBroadcast');
};
```

**VIEW**

```
<my-component ng-model="message"></my-component>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @grion_13 answer, scope:true would also work since it creates a new scope that is child of the parent scope so has access to parent scope data.

But a true reusable directive is one which get it input data using isolated scope. This way as long as your html+ controller can provide the right arguments to the directive isolated scope, you can use the directive in any view.